# Angular build throws "Optimization error" after upgrading to Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

We recently upgraded to Angular 12 and now get this error:

```
Error: Optimization error [vendor-es2015.a2045e51a8769565ebf3.js]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at onParseError (node:internal/url:552:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:628:5)
    at normalizeSimplePath (/Users/Shared/Projects/juicier-projects/frontend/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:301:26)
    at normalizePath (/Users/Shared/Projects/juicier-projects/frontend/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:320:20)
    at resolve (/Users/Shared/Projects/juicier-projects/frontend/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:386:26)
    at resolve$1 (/Users/Shared/Projects/juicier-projects/frontend/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:418:16)
    at /Users/Shared/Projects/juicier-projects/frontend/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:738:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

The error goes away if I turn off script optimization.

Also, I tried logging the param to

```
resolve$1
```

And the last param before the error is:

```
webpack://./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/localize": "12.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "12.2.8",
    "@cloudflare/stream-angular": "^0.1.3",
    "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "^12.0.0",
    "@iplab/ngx-color-picker": "1.0.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-option-highlight": "^0.0.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "5.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.5.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.5.1",
    "@sentry/angular": "^6.13.3",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.13.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.18.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "19.0.1",
    "angular-email-editor": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-fittext": "^2.1.1",
    "angulartics2": "^11.0.0",
    "animate-css-grid": "^1.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "color": "^4.0.1",
    "country-emoji": "^1.5.6",
    "email-providers": "^1.0.3",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "firebase-admin": "8.11.0",
    "firebaseui": "^4.8.0",
    "firebaseui-angular": "5.1.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.2",
    "gsap": "^3.1.1",
    "ionicons": "^4.4.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.12",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.1.9",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.7",
    "logrocket-ngrx": "^0.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mustache": "^3.0.1",
    "network-information-types": "^0.1.0",
    "ng-hcaptcha": "^1.1.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^10.0.0",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^3.0.1",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^12.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.1",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "5.0.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-photo-editor": "^0.3.1",
    "ngx-quicklink": "^0.2.7",
    "ngx-quill": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^9.3.0",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-delta": "^4.2.2",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
    "quill-mention": "^3.0.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "variable-diff": "^2.0.2",
    "xdomain-cookies": "git+https://github.com/eni9889/xdomain-cookies.git",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "12.1.3",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/helper-regex": "^7.10.5",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@firebase/util": "^0.2.28",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "12.2.8",
    "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.8.1",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.0",
    "chromatic": "^5.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "concat-files": "^0.1.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.9.0",
    "git-branch-is": "^2.0.0",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
    "husky": "^1.0.0-rc.13",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "merge-files": "^0.1.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "prettier": "1.12.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.34.7",
    "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "stylelint": "13.13.1",
    "tmp": "^0.2.1",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "typescript-tslint-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "win-node-env": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn run lint:ci"
    }
  }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I'd be happy to provide any other info as well. I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find any other people who have run into this.

Comment: share your angular.json as well and the command  u are using to build.